# How to install the latest Linux Kernel, Mesa, Intel/AMD GPU drivers, and Xorg.. on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kernel, graphics, ppa

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, how to get:

- **Linux Kernel:** 5.0 or newer.
- **Mesa Library:** 19.0 or newer.
- **Intel Graphics Driver:** ...? (latest)
- **AMD Graphics Driver:** ...? (latest)
- **Xorg:** ...? (latest)

I have two machines, one with a GPU from Intel, the other from AMD.

Another way to ask this question would be: **how to optimize gaming (e.g. Steam) and make the most out of newish-hardware, specifically on *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS*?**

Comment: If you want newer software, use a newer release of Ubuntu. Frankensteining your older system with newer organs and limbs will simply make it unpredictable and afraid of fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this for AMD](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers), it has a guide on the page.